# Broken Fill Tool

Tags: modeling

Heyo, the blender noob has returned. This time, it appears my Fill tool has randomly decided to hate me. Whenever I select my verts then press the hotkey to Fill a space, I get this lovely error message:

[image]

I have the mirror mod on, but that's never been a problem before. This has never HAPPENED before. There's no doubles, and I DO have the correct amount of verts selected as well as the LoopTools ticked in my prefs. Not sure what's going on or what I might've pressed to screw this up. Help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8m_HvAY0QvmR05aN2dQTlIxY28
Here's the blend, Go crazy.

Comment: actually works for me... do you tried reload blender file or reinstall?

Comment: This message could be the behaviour of the Alt+F tool, which fills with triangles. Are you sure you press F to fill ?

Comment: Very sure. Tried Alt+F too. Same thing.

Comment: how many points are you trying to connect? is there a strange geometry between them? Can you upload an example of this failing?

Comment: A photo has been added. I know for a fact that it's possible to connect those four points; i've connected them before.

Comment: Alt+F **will** give that error because there isn't any perimeter defined. What I wanted to know is do you really press F while filling and do you have any modifiers except for the Mirror. I can't repeat that behaviour with default Blender. Probably you should [upload .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to allow others to look into it.

Comment: Added. Go crazy.

Comment: I still can't repeat that behaviour, [it works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7g49.gif) and I'm not aware of any way to get that error while pressing F. Check once again that you're pressing F after selecting.

Comment: Been pressin' F for a while now. I'm gonna completely erase it from my computer and reinstall it, and I'll update this once I do.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps its the way the vertices are selected. Try
 CTRL+TAB edge select , 
select 2 opposite edges (the ones going vertical look like good candidates)
FKEY 
also SPACE Grid Fill